# C# downloadasync wait for download to finish

Tags: c#

Is it possible to wait for the download to finish then executing the next line of code?

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("url"), @"c:\tmp\file.exe");
wb.DownloadProgressChanged += wb_DownloadProgressChanged;
wb.DownloadFileCompleted += wb_DownloadFileCompleted;
//Code to run after download finished...
```

I know I can just use wb.DownloadFile but that wont give feedback on download percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the .net 4.5 you can take advantage of the new `async/await` keywords and the [DownloadFileTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
async void DownloadSomeFile()
{
   WebClient wb = new WebClient();
   wb.DownloadProgressChanged += wb_DownloadProgressChanged;
   wb.DownloadFileCompleted += wb_DownloadFileCompleted;

   await wb.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("url"), @"c:\tmp\file.exe");

   //Do the other work here
}
```

Comment: @Aberto is it possible to use async and await inside a method?

Comment: @Johnny If you want to use await, you need to mark your method as async

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the new `await` keyword that was introduced in .Net 4.5 along with the Async methods.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx) for a walkthrough on MSDN of how to make the code wait for the download to finish.